# Mocking using mocha in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js

How can I mock a client and a server in Mocha using NodeJs.
Specifically, I have the following code:

```
app.post ('path name', function (req, res) { 
  // Some Action 
  res.send(response); 
});
```

I want to mock the `req`, `res` parameters and test `res` (status, header, message).

Answer (score 27):

Mocha itself doesn't provide mock/stub/spy type functionality. [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) is a popular library that does. The home page includes examples of testing ajax as well as their Fake XMLHTTPRequest object.

Comment: Could you be clearer on whether you are trying to perform integration tests or unit testing? An answer to this would be misinformed unless this is known.

Comment: @SonOfNun Since he's talking about mocking responses, he's mostly likely referring to unit tests. But you are right, needs to be made clear in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

I found [Node-Fakeweb](https://github.com/ctide/fakeweb) useful

```
var request = require('request'); 
  // Mocking a client request 
  request.get({ uri: 'URI', body: 'body' }, function (err, resp, body) {
    // Some Action
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mocha with [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to mock a request. Here is a wonderful tutorial about how to do it:
http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/how-to-build-and-test-rest-api-with-nodejs-express-mocha/

Comment: `Supertest` is used for integration testing, not unit testing, since it hits real endpoints and requires database backend.